# Replace exact content into file from cat results though terminal

Tags: linux, perl, sed, terminal

I would like dynamically to change some values on a file, with name waf.py.

the line is like this

```
pp.pprint(api.post("/sites/<SITEID>/waf", {}))
```

I have stored value to another file with name `.adnid`

I am processing with command

```
perl -pe 's/<SITEID>/`cat .adnid`/ge' -i waf.py
```

It replaces the contents but it add `\n` (enter) on it and the remaining content goes to a new row, like

```
pp.pprint(api.post("/sites/626041
/waf", {}))
```

Instead of excepted (1 row)

```
pp.pprint(api.post("/sites/626041/waf", {}))
```

How can I make it work without the newline?

Comment: `cat` appends a newline.

Comment: Are there any other way to do this please instead of cat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cat`, but you need to `chomp` off the newline it appends.

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $id=`cat .adnid`; chomp $id } s/<SITEID>/$id/ge' -i waf.py
```

This adds a `BEGIN` block that will only be executed once. The variable gets read using `cat` and then `chomp`ed. The substitution is applied to every line of your file. This has the additional benefit that you don't shell out to `cat` for every single line of input.

Note that `BEGIN` behaves differently than normal with `-p`. This is documented in [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END) somewhere close to the large block of examples.

A more Perlish way would be to use `open` and actually read from the file, which you would also have to do in a `BEGIN` block. But for a throw-away script it doesn't really matter and the `cat` way is shorter.

Comment: Thanks it works as excepted !! Thank you very much your valuable help. Wish you all the best !!